# Android Studio installs a different version of my react-native app compared to running it from command line

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

I recently jumped onto a project using react-native and am relatively new to it. When I run the app on my phone through `react-native run-android`, it runs the version of the app that I want. However, when I open the `app` from the `android` folder in Android Studio and run it on my phone from there, it runs a different version of the app (different from running through `react-native run-android`). I need to open the command line version in Android Studio so I can make a signed APK to upload to the play store.

Any help as to why this is happening would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. For anyone who finds themselves in a similar situation:

Any changes to the react-native code will not apply to the android version until it is rebundled. This is because when the app is run through `react-native run-android` it starts a bundling service automatically (same as running `npm start`) so it automatically bundles the project. However, when running through android studio, it does not do this. Therefore, you must bundle it yourself before opening it in android studio. 
To do this, run the following command in the cmd in your project directory

`react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`

After running this, you should be able to open the `android` folder in android studio and it will run the latest version of your app.